# Display JOIN results in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I'm doing JOIN like this:

```
$selectData = array('zamowienia.id_zamowienia','czas','data_zamowienia','dostawa','uwagi','na_wynos','kod_odbioru','adres','nazwa');

$this->db->select($selectData);
$this->db->from('zamowienia');
$this->db->join('oferta_zamowienia','oferta_zamowienia.id_zamowienia = zamowienia.id_zamowienia');
$this->db->join('oferta','oferta.id_oferta = oferta_zamowienia.id_oferta');

if($query->num_rows()!=0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```

In the result I have arrays of arrays that got the same data except one 'nazwa'. How can i display all 'nazwa' that have the same 'id_zamowienia'?

Comment: how about a where clause?

Comment: i suggest u write the query in full sql statement.
but using query binding feature in CI which also escape the value.

im using CI3 in developing my site, but hardly use this built-in query feature because its quite hard to understand it in some way.